# C# DateTime to UTC Time without changing the time

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

How would I convert a preexisting datetime to UTC time without changing the actual time.

Example:

```
DateTime dateTime = GetSomeDateTime(); // dateTime here is 3pm
dateTime.ToUtcDateTime() // datetime should still be 3pm
```

Comment: You're in ***PST*** ? How do you get `PST` value?

Answer (score 273, accepted):

```
6/1/2011 4:08:40 PM Local
6/1/2011 4:08:40 PM Utc
```

from

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;            
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", dt, dt.Kind);
DateTime ut = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dt, DateTimeKind.Utc);
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", ut, ut.Kind);
```

Comment: Considering net framework 4.8 and older there's a bug with time zones. Net 5.0 (which is the latest version for the time I post this comment) is OK. See here my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69221062/6435004

Comment: Just stumbled on this. Be aware that if you parse a DateTime from a Iso string "YYYY-MM-ddTHH-mm-ss" that you don't add a "Z" at the end. Otherwise SpecifyKind will change your hours.

Answer (score 72):

Use the [`DateTime.SpecifyKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.specifykind) static method.

> Creates a new DateTime object that has the same number of ticks as the specified DateTime, but is designated as either local time, Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), or neither, as indicated by the specified DateTimeKind value.

Example:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime other = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);

Console.WriteLine(dateTime + " " + dateTime.Kind); // 6/1/2011 4:14:54 PM Local
Console.WriteLine(other + " " + other.Kind);       // 6/1/2011 4:14:54 PM Utc
```

Answer (score 32):

You can use the overloaded constructor of `DateTime`:

```
DateTime utcDateTime = new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, dateTime.Hour, dateTime.Minute, dateTime.Second, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Comment: The solution is a bit awkward for the OP's question, but worked well for me for creating a new brand new `DateTime`.

Answer (score -1):

create the extension lib in a static class

```
   public static ToUtcDateTime(this DateTime datetime)
    {
        return DateTime.SpecifyKind(datetime,DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }
```

the above should work fine

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide more information than the previous answers, I think you should read [the help center for answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) and especially [How to answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Reasons to delete answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score -10):

Use the `DateTime.ToUniversalTime` method.

Comment: that changes the dateTime to be 11pm (I am in PST)