# How to set a time zone (or a Kind) of a DateTime value?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

I mean to store strict UTC time in a DateTime variable and output it in ISO 8601 format.

To do the last I've used `.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz")`, and it has uncovered that the time zone is UTC+01:00.

I've tried to use `.Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc`, but it says the Kind property has no setter.

How do I explicitly specify the time is in UTC? How is the Kind property set?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

While the DateTime.Kind property does not have a setter, the static method [DateTime.SpecifyKind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.datetime.specifykind%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) creates a DateTime instance with a specified value for Kind.

Altenatively there are several [DateTime constructor overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.datetime.datetime(v=VS.100).aspx) that take a DateTimeKind parameter

Comment: The `DateTimeKind` only contains local, unspecified and UTC. It is probably not possible I want to using one particular time zone.

Comment: @hardywang If all you need is to specify a time and an offset from UTC then you can use [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx).  If you really need to identify a particular time zone then you need to combine DateTime with a [TimeZoneInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx).  See [Choosing Between DateTime, DateTimeOffset, and TimeZoneInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267.aspx) for a discussion.

Comment: DateTimeKind does not really do a great deal other than act as a point of reference when converting times. It does not actually change anything if you apply it to an existing DateTime.

Answer (score 77):

If you want to get advantage of your local machine timezone you can use `myDateTime.ToUniversalTime()` to get the UTC time from your local time or `myDateTime.ToLocalTime()` to convert the UTC time to the local machine's time.

```
// convert UTC time from the database to the machine's time
DateTime databaseUtcTime = new DateTime(2011,6,5,10,15,00);
var localTime = databaseUtcTime.ToLocalTime();

// convert local time to UTC for database save
var databaseUtcTime = localTime.ToUniversalTime();
```

If you need to convert time from/to other timezones, you may use `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime()` or `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc()`.

```
// convert UTC time from the database to japanese time
DateTime databaseUtcTime = new DateTime(2011,6,5,10,15,00);
var japaneseTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time");
var japaneseTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(databaseUtcTime, japaneseTimeZone);

// convert japanese time to UTC for database save
var databaseUtcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(japaneseTime, japaneseTimeZone);
```

[List of available timezones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749073.aspx)

[TimeZoneInfo class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx)

Answer (score 13):

You can try this as well, it is easy to implement

```
TimeZone time2 = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
DateTime test = time2.ToUniversalTime(DateTime.Now);
var singapore = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Singapore Standard Time");
var singaporetime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(test, singapore);
```

Change the text to which standard time you want to change.

Use `TimeZone` feature of C# to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I hit the time zone problem in System.DateTime in net framework 4.8. I suppose there's a bug in this version of framework.

I ran this piece of code under net framework 4.8 and net 5.0 (+3 is my local time zone).

```
var dateTime = new DateTime(2021, 3, 3, 12, 13, 14);
var dateTimeKindUtc = new DateTime(2021, 3, 3, 12, 13, 14, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var dateTimeSpecifyKind = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var dateTimeToUniversalTime = dateTime.ToUniversalTime();
var timeZoneInfoConvertTimeToUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTime);

Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(dateTime)} {dateTime:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz}");
Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(dateTimeKindUtc)} {dateTimeKindUtc:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz}");
Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(dateTimeSpecifyKind)} {dateTimeSpecifyKind:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz}");
Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(dateTimeToUniversalTime)} {dateTimeToUniversalTime:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz}");
Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(timeZoneInfoConvertTimeToUtc)} {timeZoneInfoConvertTimeToUtc:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz}");
```

net framework 4.8 output

```
dateTime 2021-03-03T12:13:14+03:00
dateTimeKindUtc 2021-03-03T12:13:14+03:00
dateTimeSpecifyKind 2021-03-03T12:13:14+03:00
dateTimeToUniversalTime 2021-03-03T09:13:14+03:00
timeZoneInfoConvertTimeToUtc 2021-03-03T09:13:14+03:00
```

net 5.0 output

```
dateTime 2021-03-03T12:13:14+03:00
dateTimeKindUtc 2021-03-03T12:13:14+00:00
dateTimeSpecifyKind 2021-03-03T12:13:14+00:00
dateTimeToUniversalTime 2021-03-03T09:13:14+00:00
timeZoneInfoConvertTimeToUtc 2021-03-03T09:13:14+00:00
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#zzzSpecifier):

With DateTime values, the "zzz" custom format specifier represents the signed offset of _the local operating system's time zone from UTC_, measured in hours and minutes. It doesn't reflect the value of an instance's DateTime.Kind property. **For this reason, the "zzz" format specifier is not recommended for use with DateTime values.**