# Convert UTC to LocalDateTime in Joda?

Tags: java, time, local, jodatime

```
        DateTime dt = new DateTime("2014-09-15T21:20:14");
        System.out.println(dt);
        System.out.println(dt.plusMillis(581042272).toDateTime().toLocalDateTime().toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("GMT")));
```

the time in dt is in UTC, I want to set the time in dt plus milliseconds to GMT? However, the time is still printed as UTC (1 hour behind GMT). How can I set it so it's one hour in front?

```
2014-09-15T21:20:14.000+01:00
2014-09-22T14:44:16.272Z
```

I know the time is exactly one hour behind because I made this request at 15:44:16 GMT

Comment: What do you mean by "the time in dt is in UTC"? That's clearly not the case given your first line of output. Do you mean `"2014-09-15T21:20:14"` is meant to be UTC?

Comment: Yes, sorry if it wasn't clear Jon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `DateTime` is actually *not* in UTC - it's in the system default time zone. To fix it, you just need to tell it that the value you're passing in is in UTC:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime("2014-09-15T21:20:14", DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println(dt);
DateTime other = dt.plusMillis(581042272);
System.out.println(other);
```

Output:

```
2014-09-15T21:20:14.000Z
2014-09-22T14:44:16.272Z
```

Also note that you can't have made the request at 15:44:16 GMT, as that hasn't occurred yet. At the time I'm writing this, it's 16:05 British Summer Time, therefore 15:05 GMT. It's important to understand that the time zone in the UK isn't "GMT" - that's just the part of the time zone when we're not observing daylight savings.

If you want to convert to the UK time zone, you want:

```
DateTime other = dt.plusMillis(581042272)
    .withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London"));
```

Answer (score 6):

For those that have trouble with converting datetime from a server to local datetime:

1.Make sure the server gives you a UTC time, meaning, the format should contain a timezone.
2.Convert with pattern, if the api does not give you an timezone, then you might get an exception because of the last 'Z'.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(currentPost.postDate);
```

3.to check the time offset (optional)

```
DateTimeZone ActualZone = dt.getZone();
```

4.Convert to local time

```
TimeZone tz2 = TimeZone.getDefault();
        DateTime localdt = new DateTime(dt, DateTimeZone.forID(tz2.getID()));
```

*(if you control the API yourself, and it happens to be an asp.net api, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239976/how-to-set-a-time-zone-or-a-kind-of-a-datetime-value), to set the `Kind` of the datetime, even though you might have saved it as UTC time in the database, you will send the datetime with the default server timezone)*

Answer (score 0):

```
val marketCentreTime = timeInAnotherTimezone.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("yourCountryName/andyourCityName"));
```