# C# ConvertTimeFromUtc funkiness

Tags: c#

With the code below, I'm trying to convert this `datetime` string to a Local `DateTime`

```
private DateTime ConvertToLocalTime(string datetimestring)
{
    DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.Parse(datetimestring);
    TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
    DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, cstZone);
    return cstTime;
}
```

This is the Exception I'm getting:

> at System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone, TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone, TimeZoneInfoOptions flags, CachedData cachedData)
>          at `System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone)`
>
> The conversion could not be completed because the supplied DateTime did not have the Kind 
>       property set correctly. For example, when the Kind property is `DateTimeKind.Local`, the 
>       source time zone must be TimeZoneInfo.Local.

The example for ConvertTimeFromUtc looks exactly like my code except I'm parsing this string into the timeUtc:
`2017-01-23T05:00:00+00:00`

If I call the Parse like this:

```
DateTime.Parse(datetimestring, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

`timeUtc.Kind.ToString()` returns "Local"

So, how do I remedy this? The times are going to be sent to me UTC.

Comment: Will this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239976/how-to-set-a-time-zone-or-a-kind-of-a-datetime-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add [DateTime.SpecifyKind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.specifykind(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private static DateTime ConvertToLocalTime(string datetimestring)
{
    DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.Parse(datetimestring);
    var dt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(timeUtc, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
    DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt, cstZone);
    return cstTime;
}
```

[.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lU8u5x)

Comment: Will test this out tomorrow. Didn't see the SpecifyKind method.

Comment: No, it works. You could check in fiddler. @MB34 error is that when he converts timeUtc.Kind is Local but timeUtc variable has UTC time. DateTime.SpecifyKind function sets  timeUtc.Kind to UTC without changing time.

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime.Parse` [converts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) the result into local time regardless of the zone specified in the input string. You have to explicitly specify that you want a UTC result, as `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` requires the DateTime value to be of kind UTC.

```
private DateTime ConvertToLocalTime(string datetimestring)
{
    DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.Parse(datetimestring, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
    TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
    DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, cstZone);
    return cstTime;
}
```

Comment: Tried this and the timeUtc.Kind was still Local.

Comment: @MB34 Did you specify AdjustToUniversal?

Comment: Yes, I did, just as I said.

Comment: @MB34, Not sure what is wrong, it is supposed to work, and I have checked it in dotnetfiddle.net and it is working also.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert to local datetime and you do not need the offset, since your string has offset info, `DateTime.Parse` will use the offset info and convert to local datetime. Then all you need to do is:

```
private static DateTime ConvertToLocalTime(string datetimestring)
{
    // Parses to local datetime
    // check the Kind property and you will see it has Local
    return DateTime.Parse(datetimestring);
}
```

If you need the local datetime with the offset info, then have a look at [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) because it is for this very purpose:

```
private static DateTimeOffset ConvertToLocalTime(string datetimestring)
{
    DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.Parse(datetimestring, null, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
    DateTimeOffset dateCst = new DateTimeOffset(timeUtc, TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset);

    return dateCst;
}
```

If you need the utc datetime converted to some other timezone, not local, then specify it like below:

```
private static DateTimeOffset ConvertToLocalTime(string datetimestring)
{
    DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.Parse(datetimestring, null, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
    TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
    DateTimeOffset dateCst = new DateTimeOffset(timeUtc, cstZone.GetUtcOffset(timeUtc));

    return dateCst;
}
```

This is the documentation:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Initializes a new instance of the System.DateTimeOffset structure using the specified
//     System.DateTime value and offset.
//
// Parameters:
//   dateTime:
//     A date and time.
//
//   offset:
//     The time's offset from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).
//
// Exceptions:
//   T:System.ArgumentException:
//     dateTime.Kind equals System.DateTimeKind.Utc and offset does not equal zero.-or-dateTime.Kind
//     equals System.DateTimeKind.Local and offset does not equal the offset of the
//     system's local time zone.-or-offset is not specified in whole minutes.
//
//   T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
//     offset is less than -14 hours or greater than 14 hours.-or-System.DateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime
//     is less than System.DateTimeOffset.MinValue or greater than System.DateTimeOffset.MaxValue.
```